# Best way to compare and update two SQL tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

What is the best way to compare two tables lets say SourceTableA and DestinationTableB?

- if data found in DestinationTableB but not existing in SourceTableA,
  insert them to SourceTableA
- else if data found in SourceTableA but not DestinationTableB, delete
  them from SourceTableA

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: You should do a stored procedure. Cursor the rows in table B. For each row in B check if exists in A. If not, insert it in A. After that cursor the rows in table A, and do the corresponding check.

Comment: Let me drive you to the right direction: Please read [ask] in [help], then edit/update your question to match the criterias there. In this form, your question is a subject of closing (Opinion based, too broad)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those two condition are mutually exclusive so you don't need an else

```
delete SourceTableA 
where not exist (select 1 from DestinationTableB 
                 where DestinationTableB.key = SourceTableA.key)

insert into SourceTableA  
select * 
from DestinationTableB 
where not exist (select 1 from SourceTableA 
                 where DestinationTableB.key = SourceTableA.key)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should to use MERGE statement to do this.

[MDSN - SQL Merge](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

[Relevant](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2008/05/13/question-needed-not-answer.aspx)

This is *very* vague, but the best choice would probably to run 2 queries, one that delete from A where it doesn't exist in B, then one that inserts B into A where it doesn't exist in A.